# How get Web API IHttpActionResult response and serialize c#

Tags: c#, api, http, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get "response, serialize and consume" the web api, I never code a web api before.

I have the following Web API:

```
 [HttpGet]     
 public IHttpActionResult SendMsg(string yourName)       
 {

        var result = "Hi " + yourName;
        if (result == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(result);
  }
```

and i'm trying to get the response with this code:

```
    private void ResponseWebAPI(string strApiAddress)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(strApiAddress) as HttpWebRequest;
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

    }
```

I'm receiving the response without any problem, but when I load the response I got the following error:

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Comment: Show what the response looks like. most probably its not coming back as xml which you are trying to load stream into. The request also doesn't specify how it wants the response (accept header).

Comment: `SendMsg` doesn't return anything in XML format. If you change it to return an XML document or a class that has the `[Serialize]` attribute on it, you should be successful.

Comment: @Nkosi, i think you're right.

Reponse:
<string>Hi Mario</string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void ResponseWebAPI(string strApiAddress) {
    var request = WebRequest.Create(strApiAddress) as HttpWebRequest;
    var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(responseString);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code.

- First, are you sure that you receive XML not JSON.
- In order to parse XML you have to write the following: [Serialize XML Response](http://www.coderslexicon.com/serializing-and-deserializing-xml-through-a-url-endpoint-in-csharp/)

My advice to you, to use `HttpClient` instead of `HttpWebRequest` like the following:

```
public async Task<Model> GetData(string url)
        {           
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage result = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string contentResult = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Model newModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(contentResult);

            }

            return newModel;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

set the request Accept header to application/json.

```
request.Accept = "application/json";
```

then consume the response as JSON.

Or, you could use HttpClient instead, which has a simpler, more modern API.

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

```
public static async Task DoAsync()
{
    var strApiAddress = "http://localhost";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var str = await client.GetStringAsync(strApiAddress);
}

public static void Do()
{
    var strApiAddress = "http://localhost";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var str = client.GetStringAsync(strApiAddress).Result;
}
```